# Pick random array of $mail values in PHPMailer

Tags: php, email, smtp, phpmailer

I have a script for mail sending via SMTP in PHPMailer, and I would like the script to randomly pick email values that will be used for email sending.

I have something like this

```
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);                             

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) 
{
try {
  $mail->SMTPDebug = 2;                                 // Enable verbose debug output
  $mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
  $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
  $mail->XMailer = ' ';
  $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
  $mail->Port = '587';
  $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
  $mail->Priority = 1;
  $mail->isHTML(true);      
  
   // $mail->Username = 'email1@gmail.com';
   // $mail->Password = 'email1apppw';
   // $mail->SetFrom('email1@gmail.com', 'Email One');
   // $mail->AddReplyTo('email1@gmail.com', 'Email One');

   $mail->Username = 'email2@gmail.com';
   $mail->Password = 'email2apppw';
   $mail->SetFrom('email2@gmail.com', 'Email One');
   $mail->AddReplyTo('email2@gmail.com', 'Email One');

   $mail->send();
```

Now, in order to send an email via **email1@gmail.com**, I have to comment out email2@gmail.com, and uncomment the email1 data.

Is it possible to randomly pick one of the 2 as arrays? If it is, I would appreciate help very much since I am stuck.

Thanks!

Comment: _..since I am stuck..._ Where are you stuck exactly?

Comment: stuck = don't know where should I start in order to implement this

Comment: _...where should I start ..._  Maybe [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rand.php)?